# Inheritance depth, Single responsability or DRY

Tags: c++, inheritance

Let's say I want to implement three different classes: *Square*, *ColoredSquare*, *TexturedSquare*.

Since *ColoredSquare* is a *Square* with a color and *TexturedSquare* is a *ColoredSquare* with a texture, my first thought was to have them all deriving from each other:

```
class Square {
    Square::Square(position)
        : position_(position)
    {
    }
}

class ColoredSquare : public Square {
    ColoredSquare::ColoredSquare(position, color)
        : Square(position), color_(color)
    {
    }
}

class TexturedSquare: public ColoredSquare {
    TexturedSquare::TexturedSquare(position, color, texture)
        : ColoredSquare(position, color), texture_(texture)
    {
    }
};
```

However, I remembered reading that having too much inheritance depth was bad practice (and that generally, classes should only be deriving from abstract classes).
So I thought about switching to a single class:

```
    class Square {
    Square::Square(glm::vec3 position)
        : position_(position), type_(SquareType::Basic)
    {
    }

    Square::Square(glm::vec3 position, glm::vec4 color)
        : position_(position), color_(color), type_(SquareType::Colored)
    {
    }

    Square::Square(glm::vec3 position, glm::vec4 color, glm::vec2 texture)
        : position_(position), color_(color), texture_(texture), type_(SquareType::Textured)
    {
    }
};
```

Now, while I find it acceptable for now, I'm thinking it might be unpractical in the future (I won't be able to use polymorphism) and I'm also wondering if this is in breach of the Single Responsability Principle.

What would be the best way to implement this hierarchy structure in a clean, extensive way?

Comment: I don't feel 2 levels of inheritance is 'too much' by any means. And if the base class is a meaningful object in its own right it does not have to be abstract imo.

Comment: will there ever be a ColouredTexturedSquare?

Comment: @Aer, I think your first code block doesn't say what you meant it to -- isn't the third class definition (1) meant to be of `TexturedSquare` rather than `ColoredSquare` and (2) meant to have `ColoredSquare` rather than `Square` as base class?

Comment: @RichardHodges, my reading of Aer's question is that a `TexturedSquare` *is* in fact a `TexturedColoredSquare`. (Using the shorter name seems benign to me.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes, you're right! Sorry for the confusion. I corrected the mistake in the question.

Comment: @user1320881 Yes, but I'm thinking that I might need to extend the class further. And staying in that same logical, would then have to derive from one of those classes and possibly adding more level. Wouldn't that be a pain to maintain, debug and eventually understand for an outsider?
As I plan on doing my first big C++ project, I'm trying to keep it as clean as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's one correct answer to this question, but there are other approaches available.

One could be to multiply inherit from pure virtual classes and implement them in the derived class:

```
class Texture {};
class Color {};
class Square {};

class ITextured { public: virtual void setTexture(Texture) = 0; };
class IColored { public: virtual void setColor(Color) = 0; };

class ColoredSquare : public IColored, public ITextured, public Square {
    Texture tex;
    Color col;
public:
    virtual void setTexture(Texture t) { tex = t; }
    virtual void setColor(Color c) { col = c; }
};
```

This avoids having issues like `Square` inherit from `Rectangle` although a Rectangle method might alter only height, leaving the derived square class in violation of square-ness.

[Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) is another approach, and there are many ways to implement similar ideas.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. I hadn't thought of it this. And it does solve the problems I can think of.
Now, you mention `Composition`, here, it would be quite similar to your solution except instead of inheriting it would just have it as a member, right?